# How do I change the date format for a site collection

Tags: 2010

I need to change the date format of the created and modified dates in every list in a site collection. I can't create a new column and I can't modify the xslt. Is there a setting in share point that I can use. Alternatively, will changing it on the web front end change it in the application?

EDIT: Here is an example of what I want to change it to e.g. yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to change it to?

Comment: How do you want to change it exactly?

Comment: @DavidLozzi I went ahead and converted your answer to a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you go to the root of the site collection (from *Site Settings* on any web, you should see a *Go to top level site settings* link if you are a Site Collection Admin, this will take you to the root).

In the root site collection, there is a *Regional Settings* link under *Site Administration*.  You can try to change the *locale*, this should change the display of dates (as well as numbers and times) in the Site Collection.

Comment: I want the local to stay the same, but it is the policy of the organization to represent all electronic dates with yyyy-MM-dd.

Comment: @user2903, how awesome that some organisations actually insist on using the international date format!..