# How to change date format to dd-mm-yyyy in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, date-format

I have a list view webpart which displays start date of calendar list. It displays date in MM/dd/yyyy format (US format). I want to change it to dd/MM/yyyy (UK format). I have tried to change it from regional setting. But nothing happens. Does it take some time to change the date format?

Is there any other OOTB way to change the date format of entire site collection in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 6):

You can modify Regional settings of the site collection. The date format will change automatically for all of existing date&time columns on that site collection.
Or just type http://yoursite:port/_layouts/regionalsetng.aspx in your web browser and change from english/locale to some other exp. german.

There is similar request answered here:
[How do I change the date format for a site collection](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21136/how-do-i-change-the-date-format-for-a-site-collection)

Comment: I have tried this solution but it didn't seem to work for me. currently we are creating a calculated column for it in every calendar list.

Answer (score 0):

There is also something else that you could check as well as Danilo's answer above, and that is the actual server language and region settings, found within Control panel.

Control Panel -> Language: Add a  language of your choice that is required, and move to the top.

Control Panel -> Region: check all 3 tabs, including Administrative, as the system locale is set there.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Regional formats in SharePoint managed by two settings:
1)site settings=>regional settings, as written before
2)User profile site=>edit details=>language and region