# Date format without spaces

Tags: formatting, date

we have migrated Sharepoint from Windows Server 2008 R2 to 2012 R2. Previously was date format without spaces (f.e. 4.1.2017), now it has to be with spaces

[image: Date with spaces]

When I delete spaces, it write text like in Picture.

I have changed date format on frontend server, but it does not help. Should I have to change date format on server with central administration, or where?

Comment: Can you check this link-
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21136/how-do-i-change-the-date-format-for-a-site-collection

Comment: I tried change of regional settings, it does not help me.

Answer (score 0):

So MS expert said, that this is MS problem and it solve that